# Are Asynchronous writes to a socket thread safe?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, io, thread-safety

Consider the `Socket.BeginSend()` method. If two thread pool threads were to call this method simultaneously, would their respective messages end up mixing with each other or does the socket class keep this from happening?

Comment: While it will work, you should only do it with an unreliable ordering datagram based protocol like UDP. The reason being that if two threads race to call BeginSend, you may get out of order sending at the source. This would result in application data corruption when using TCP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a smiliar [post on the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/53aa930e-ce51-4993-a23b-040905aed46f/) which seems to answer to your question.

> 1. You can queue multiple BeginSends at the same time. You don't need to lock

Edit:

Even more interesting informations:

If you scroll down a bit in the [Remark section of the MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38dxf7kt.aspx) BeginSend(), you will find interesting use of callback methods that could be relevant for you.

> [...] If you want the original thread to block after you call the BeginSend method, use the WaitHandle.WaitOne method. [...]

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for! THANKS!

Answer (score 17):

.NET Socket instances are not thread-safe in that simultaneous calls to some methods (the same or different ones) may cause inconsistent state.  However, the **`BeginSend()` and `BeginReceive()` methods are thread-safe with respect to themselves**.

**It is safe to have multiple outstanding calls to each (or both).**

In the case of `BeginReceive()`, they will be serviced when data is available in the order called. This can be useful if, for example, your processing is lengthy but you want other receives to occur as quickly as possible. Of course in this case you may have your code processing multiple receipts simultaneously and you may need your own synchronization logic to protect your application state.

In the case of `BeginSend()`, each call will attempt to push the sent data into the socket buffer, and as soon as it is accepted there, your callback will be called (where you will call `EndSend()`). If there is insufficient buffer space for any call, it will block.

Note: don't assume that the default 8k buffer means "I can quickly call `BeginSend()` with exactly 8k of data, then it will block," as the following are true:

1. The 8K is a "nominal size" number, and the buffer may shrink and grow somewhat
2. As you are queing up the 8K worth of calls, data will be being sent on the network reducing that 8K of queued data

In general:

- If you call `BeginSend()` several times within a thread, you are assured that the sends will leave the machine in the order they were called.
- If you call `BeginSend()` from several threads, there is no guarantee of order unless you use some other blocking mechanism to force the actual calls to occur in some specific order. Each call however will send its data properly in one contiguous stream of network bytes.

Comment: Your answer came a couple years after the original question and I am just now seeing it (another year later) but I want you to know that it had great detail and I really appreciate it. Though, my own personal knowledge of the .Net framework and my skill as a developer are far past this question now, this answer will be a great resource for future readers. If I had not already checked an answer as the correct answer years ago, I'd give you the correct answer. Much appreciated.