# Improving TCP forwarder using Socket in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets, tcp

I have Implemented a simple TCP forwarder which is connected to a backend server. This server is set on `http://localhost:5000` and this TCP forwarder is listening to `http://localhost:5001`. Using another machine to generate load using `wrk` [which is a HTTP benchmarking tool to generator load](https://github.com/wg/wrk), I have 2 different results. When I send the load directly to the service which is based on `asp.net core web api` on the `kestrel` more than 230K requests/second are handled but when I send the load to this TCP forwarder 83Krequest/second can be handled. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace BrunoGarcia.Net
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new TcpForwarderSlim().Start(
            new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(args[0]), int.Parse(args[1])),
            new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(args[2]), int.Parse(args[3])));
    }
    public class TcpForwarderSlim
    {
        private readonly Socket _mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        public void Start(IPEndPoint local, IPEndPoint remote)
        {
            _mainSocket.Bind(local);
            _mainSocket.Listen(10);

            while (true)
            {
                var source = _mainSocket.Accept();
                var destination = new TcpForwarderSlim();
                var state = new State(source, destination._mainSocket);
                destination.Connect(remote, source);
                source.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, 0, OnDataReceive, state);
            }
        }

        private void Connect(EndPoint remoteEndpoint, Socket destination)
        {
            var state = new State(_mainSocket, destination);
            _mainSocket.Connect(remoteEndpoint);
            _mainSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnDataReceive, state);
        }

        private static void OnDataReceive(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var state = (State)result.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                var bytesRead = state.SourceSocket.EndReceive(result);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    state.DestinationSocket.Send(state.Buffer, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
                    state.SourceSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, 0, OnDataReceive, state);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                state.DestinationSocket.Close();
                state.SourceSocket.Close();
            }
        }

        private class State
        {
            public Socket SourceSocket { get; private set; }
            public Socket DestinationSocket { get; private set; }
            public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

            public State(Socket source, Socket destination)
            {
                SourceSocket = source;
                DestinationSocket = destination;
                Buffer = new byte[8192];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem do you think?! How can I improve the result when I use TCP forwarder?!Or is there a better way to make a tunnel or a forwarder to listen to a port and send the TCP requests to one of 2 or more back end service?!

Answer (score 1):

You do not start listening for a more data till `state.DestinationSocket.Send` completes. You can start listening for more data as soon as you start processing the Send, [the order of multiple `BeginSend` calls is preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10254819/80274) so if you switched to that it would allow you to start processing the next request before the previous one finished.

**Important note!** You will now need to create a new buffer (or use a pool of buffers) for each new BeginReceive request. Below is untested code but hopefully is close enough to get you on the right path.

```
public class TcpForwarderSlim
{
    private readonly Socket _mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    public void Start(IPEndPoint local, IPEndPoint remote)
    {
        _mainSocket.Bind(local);
        _mainSocket.Listen(10);

        while (true)
        {
            var source = _mainSocket.Accept();
            var destination = new TcpForwarderSlim();
            var state = new State(source, destination._mainSocket);
            destination.Connect(remote, source);
            source.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, 0, OnDataReceive, state);
        }
    }

    private void Connect(EndPoint remoteEndpoint, Socket destination)
    {
        var state = new State(_mainSocket, destination);
        _mainSocket.Connect(remoteEndpoint);
        _mainSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnDataReceive, state);
    }

    private static void OnDataReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var state = (State)result.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            var bytesRead = state.SourceSocket.EndReceive(result);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                //Start an asyncronous send.
                var sendAr = state.DestinationSocket.BeginSend(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None,null,null);

                //Get or create a new buffer for the state object.
                var oldBuffer = state.ReplaceBuffer();

                state.SourceSocket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, 0, OnDataReceive, state);

                //Wait for the send to finish.
                state.DestinationSocket.EndSend(sendAr);

                //Return byte[] to the pool.
                state.AddBufferToPool(oldBuffer);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            state.DestinationSocket.Close();
            state.SourceSocket.Close();
        }
    }

    private class State
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentBag<byte[]> _bufferPool = new ConcurrentBag<byte[]>();
        private readonly int _bufferSize;
        public Socket SourceSocket { get; private set; }
        public Socket DestinationSocket { get; private set; }
        public byte[] Buffer { get; private set; }

        public State(Socket source, Socket destination)
        {
            SourceSocket = source;
            DestinationSocket = destination;
            _bufferSize = Math.Min(SourceSocket.ReceiveBufferSize, DestinationSocket.SendBufferSize);
            Buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Replaces the buffer in the state object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The previous buffer.</returns>
        public byte[] ReplaceBuffer()
        {
            byte[] newBuffer;
            if (!_bufferPool.TryTake(out newBuffer))
            {
                newBuffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
            }
            var oldBuffer = Buffer;
            Buffer = newBuffer;
            return oldBuffer;
        }

        public void AddBufferToPool(byte[] buffer)
        {
            _bufferPool.Add(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution completely downgraded rps to 10K! :|

Comment: It was worth a shot. There might be better ways to optimize this kind of solution. I would use a profiler on the two versions and see where the hotsopts are for both. Also try this solution with larger or smaller buffer sizes. I thought my `Math.Min(SourceSocket.ReceiveBufferSize, DestinationSocket.SendBufferSize);` would help but maybe it hurt the performance.